# passwd succeeded, had no effect

Tags: ssh, root, passwd

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to change the password of the root account. I tried the following procedure:

- Login with my own account (that has the `sudo` permission)
- `sudo su root`
- `passwd`

  - Enter the new password twice.
  - I confirmed it said `passwd: password updated successfully`
- `exit`
- Trying to login root account with the new password via SSH --> FAIL!

Why `passwd` command does not work here?

Comment: Did you try to log in using `su -` or equivalent from your existing account? What is `PermitRootLogin` set to in /etc/ssh/sshd_config? BTW, it's not recommended to enable password access to the root account via SSH: it would be better to set up key-based authentication

Comment: 'PermitRootLogin' in /etc/ssh/sshd_config was the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to log in with a password to the root account over SSH, as well as setting the root password you need to set

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

in the remote system's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

*NOTE: this is not recommended because it opens the root account to brute-force attack: if you need to log in to the root account directly over SSH (instead of logging in with a non-root account, and then using* `sudo`*), it is preferable to set up key-based authentication and set* `PermitRootLogin without-password` *instead*.